# Powershell script to export all storage accounts in all subscriptions with containers/blob public access level

Tags: azure-powershell

I'm looking for a powershell script that will list all storage accounts in all subscriptions with containers/blobs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all storage account with containers/blobs in one subcsription, please refer to the following script:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "your subscrition id"
# get all accounts in one subscription 
 $accounts=Get-AzStorageAccount
 foreach($account in $accounts){
     Write-Host "list all containers in the account "$account.StorageAccountName -ForegroundColor Red
     $keys=Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $account.ResourceGroupName -Name $account.StorageAccountName
     $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $keys[0].Value
     #get all containers in one account
     $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx

     foreach($container in $containers){

     #get all blobs in one container 
      Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $ctx 

     }


 }
```

Comment: @Alex Do you have any other concern?

Comment: thank you for the script, would it be possible to also get all storage account with containers/blobs for ALL subscriptions?

Comment: You need to provide the different subscription ID when you login.